# Need book title - at intersection of 3 empires a planet with a warlike race

Tags: story-identification, warfare, races

At the intersection of 3 galactic empires (one of which is human)
There is a planet guarded by all 3 because that race is too warlike

Answer (score 2):

Your description reminds me of [Jack Vance's Planet of Adventure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_Adventure). Could it be the novel you're referring to?

From the [Planet-of-Adventure Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_of_Adventure):

> In the novels, **Tschai is a planet [...], 212 light-years from Earth**. It is populated by **three alien, mutually hostile species**; the displaced, native Pnume; and various human races, some of whom live as slaves or clients of the aliens.

(my emphasis)

Comment: Doubt it's this, but any opportunity to mention the much-beloved **Servants of the Wankh** is always welcome.